# bash: looping over the files with extra conditions

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, conditional-statements

In the working directory there are several files grouped into several groups based on the end-suffix of the file name. Here is the example for 4 groups:

```
# group 1 has 5 files
NpXynWT_apo_300K_1.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_300K_2.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_300K_3.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_300K_4.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_300K_5.pdb
# group 2 has two files
NpXynWT_apo_340K_1.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_340K_2.pdb
# group 3 has 4 files
NpXynWT_com_300K_1.pdb
NpXynWT_com_300K_2.pdb
NpXynWT_com_300K_3.pdb
NpXynWT_com_300K_4.pdb
# group 4 has 1 file
NpXynWT_com_340K_1.pdb
```

I have wrote a simple bash workflow to

1. List item pre-process each of the fille via SED: add something within each of file
2. `cat` together the pre-processed files that belongs **to the same group**

Here is my script for the realisation of the workflow where I created an array with the names of the groups and looped it according to file index from 1 to 5

```
# list of 4 groups
systems=(NpXynWT_apo_300K NpXynWT_apo_340K NpXynWT_com_300K NpXynWT_com_340K)

 # loop over the groups
for model in "${systems[@]}"; do  
    # loop over the files inside of each group
    for i in {0001..0005}; do
    # edit file via SED
    sed -i "1 i\This is $i file of the group" "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_"$i"_FA.pdb
    done
# after editing cat the pre-processed filles
  cat "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_[1-5]_FA.pdb > "${output}/${model}.pdb"
done
```

The questions to improve this script:
1) how it would be possible to add within the inner (while) loop some checking conditions (e.g. by means of IF statement) to consider **only existing files**? In my example the script always loops 5 files (for each group) according to the maximum number in one of the group (here 5 files in the first group)

```
for i in {0001..0005}; do
```

I would rather to loop along all of the existing files of the given group and break the while loop in the case if the file does not exist (e.g. considering the 4th group with only 1 file). Here is the example, which however does not work properly

```
 # loop over the groups with the checking of the presence of the file
for model in "${systems[@]}"; do  
    i="0"
    # loop over the files inside of each group
    for i in {0001..9999}; do
    if [ ! -f "${pdbs}/${model}_00${i}_FA.pdb" ]; then
echo 'File '${pdbs}/${model}_00${i}_FA.pdb' does not exits!'
    break
    else
    # edit file via SED
    sed -i "1 i\This is $i file of the group" "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_00"$i"_FA.pdb
    i=$[$i+1]
    fi
    done
done
```

Would it be possible to loop over any number of existing filles from the group (rather than just restricting to given e.g. very big number of files by

```
for i in {0001..9999}; do?
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You can check if a file exists with the `-f` test, and `break` if it doesn't:

   ```
   if [ ! -f "${pdbs}/${model}_${i}_FA.pdb" ]; then
      break
   fi
   ```
2. You existing `cat` command already does only count the existing files in each group, because `"${pdbs}"/"${model}"_[1-5]_FA.pdb` bash is performing filename expansion here, not simply expanding the `[1-5]` to all possible values. You can see this in the following example:

   ```
   > touch f1 f2 f5   # files f3 and f4 do not exist
   > echo f[1-5]
   f1 f2 f5
   ```

   Notice that `f[1-5]` did not expand to `f1 f2 f3 f4 f5`.

**Update**:

If you want your glob expression to match files ending in numbers bigger than 9, the `[1-n]` syntax will not work. The reason is that the `[...]` syntax defines a pattern that matches a single character. For instance, the expression `foo[1-9]` will match files `foo1` through `foo9`, but not `foo10` or `foo99`.

Doing something like `foo[1-99]` does not work, because it doesn't mean what you might think it means. The inside of the `[]` can contain any number of individual characters, or ranges of characters. For example, `[1-9a-nxyz]` would match any character from `'1'` through `'9'`, from `'a'` through `'n'`, or any of the characters `'x'`, `'y'`, or `'z'`, but it would *not* match `'0'`, `'q'`, `'r'`, etc. Or for that matter, it would also not match any uppercase letters.

So `[1-99]` is not interpreted as the range of *numbers* from 1-99, it is interpreted as the set of *characters* comprised of the range from '1' to '9', plus the individual character '9'. Therefore the patterns `[1-9]` and `[1-99]` are equivalent, and will only match characters `'1'` through `'9'`. The second `9` in the latter expression is redundant.

However, you can still achieve what you want with extended globs, which you can enable with the command `shopt -s extglob`:

```
> touch f1 f2 f5 f99 f100000 f129828523
> echo f[1-99999999999]       # Doesn't work like you want it to
f1 f2 f5
> shopt -s extglob
> echo f+([0-9])
f1 f2 f5 f99 f100000 f129828523
```

The `+([0-9])` expression is an extended glob expression composed of two parts: the `[0-9]`, whose meaning should be obvious at this point, and the enclosing `+(...)`.

The `+(pattern)` syntax is an `extglob` expression that means match one or more instances of `pattern`. In this case, our pattern is `[0-9]`, so the `extglob` expression `+([0-9])` matches any string of digits 0-9.

However, you should note that this means it also matches things like `000000000`. If you are only interested in numbers greater than or equal to 1, you would instead do (with `extglob` enabled):

```
> echo f[1-9]*([0-9])
```

Note the `*(pattern)` here instead of `+(pattern)`. The `*` means match *zero* or more instances of pattern. Which we want because we've already matched the first digit with `[1-9]`. For instance, `f[1-9]+([0-9])` does not match the filename `f1`.

You may not want to leave `extglob` enabled in your whole script, particularly if you have any regular glob expression elsewhere in your script that might accidentally be interpreted as an `extglob` expression. To disable `extglob` when you're done with it, do:

```
shopt -u extglob
```

There's one other important thing to note here. If a glob pattern doesn't match *any* files, then it is interpreted as a raw string, and is left unmodified.

For example:

```
> echo This_file_totally_does_not_exist*
This_file_totally_does_not_exist*
```

Or more to the point in your case, suppose there are zero files in your 4th case, e.g. there are no files containing `NpXynWT_com_340K`. In this case, if you try to use a glob containing `NpXynWT_com_340K`, you get the entire glob as a literal string:

```
> shopt -s extglob
> echo NpXynWT_com_340K_[1-9]*([0-9])
echo NpXynWT_com_340K_[1-9]*([0-9])
```

This is obviously not what you want, especially in the middle of your script where you are trying to `cat` the matching files. Luckily there is another option you can set to make non-matching globs expand to nothing:

```
> shopt -s nullglob
> echo This_file_totally_does_not_exist*   # prints nothing
```

As with `extglob`, there may be unintended behavior elsewhere in your script if you leave `nullglob` on.

Comment: thank you so much! so for the the second question I can simply indicate cat "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_[1-999999]_FA.pdb for any number of files? Are there some value for the "infinity" instead of 99999 ? :-)

Comment: @user3470313 Actually, I was mistaken about how bash expands `[1-999999]`. It will **not** work. The `[x-y]` syntax is a pattern match expression that only matches a single character. So`[1-9]` is as far as you can go when trying to match numbers 1-N. What `[1-999999]` actually means is the set of characters '1' through '9', plus the characters '9', '9', '9', '9', or '9'. For instance, you could do `[1-9abc]` and it would match any of the following *characters*: `{ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c' }`. But `foo[1-99]` does *not* match the filename `foo99`.

Comment: @user3470313 See my update above for a way to form an extended glob that would match any number from 1 to infinity.

Comment: thanks so much again Mike! the only question about the first part of my task when I need to introduce IF statement to break the while loop in the case if the file with the given index does-not exist. Actually I tried to do it with my script (please see my first post corrected) but the loop with the condition does not works properly. How it would be possible to fix it? Thanks in advance again!

Comment: Why did you add a `00` in front of the `${i}` in your fixed code?

Comment: because actually I have alot of files (like group1_001.pdb .. group1_999.pdb) which will be recognized by some another program on the next step for which it would be better to number it as 001 002 etc

Comment: probably for my case it would be better to use the second inner for loop instead of while: for i in {0001..9999}; do so the question is to break it for the non existing filles

Comment: Well I don't see any reason that `if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then break; fi` should not work. What do you mean when you say it's not working?